# element after a flexbox not positioning properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I'm trying to create a layout using flexboxes.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGvJpX?editors=1100

I don't really understand how I'm supposed to get the footer element (the green thing) to appear after the flexbox, instead of behind it as shown in the codepen.

** EDIT ** forgot to mention that the position: fixed is in there in order for .stream to have it's own scrollbar that automatically extends to the size of the window.

Here is the code:

```css
html,
body {
  background: grey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  background: blue;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.outer .boxA {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  background: pink;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.outer .boxC {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  background: yellow;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.outer .inner {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 600px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.outer .inner .stream {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 0;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="boxA">
    <h3>Some content</h3>
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="header">
      <h2>blah</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="stream">
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxC">
    <h3>Box C</h3>
    <p>yadda yadda</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `footer` is behind the `outer` element because
>   being a `fixed` element `outer` is removed from the normal flow of the
>   DOM elements. You don't need `position: fixed` here - remove it and get the `footer` right below the `flexbox`.

If filling everything in the viewport is what you desire, you can use viewport units (`vh`) instead of `position: fixed` to get the effect of filling everything in the viewport.

So here is something that will get you started:

1. Removed `position: fixed` for the `outer` element
2. Wrapped `outer` and `footer` into a `wrapper` element with column flex-flow:

   ```
   .wrapper{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     height: 100vh;
   }
   ```

   Also distribute `100vh` to the `footer` and `outer` element- say for illustration `90vh` for `outer` and `10vh` for `footer`
3. Give `overflow-y: auto` to `outer` and `flex-shrink: 0` to `header`.
4. For smaller viewport heights, the margin of `p` in `footer` may cause overflow of `body`- you can set `margin: 0` for the p.

```css
html,
body {
  background: grey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  background: blue;
  flex-shrink: 0; 
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 90vh;
}
.outer .boxA {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  background: pink;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.outer .boxC {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  background: yellow;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.outer .inner {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  width: 600px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.outer .inner .stream {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 0;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10vh;
}
.footer p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="outer">
    <div class="boxA">
      <h3>Some content</h3>
      <p>blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="header">
        <h2>blah</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="stream">
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
        <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxC">
      <h3>Box C</h3>
      <p>yadda yadda</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

For `column` flex-direction I guess it is a little bit tricky to adjust the `overflow`s and `height`s unless you use viewport heights throughout the nested flexboxes.

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation and solution using height:100vh. This was the real missing piece for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the footer at the bottom of a `div.outer`?

If so, just change this:

```
.outer { display:flex; position:fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0;}
```

to this:

```
.outer { display:flex; top: 0; bottom: 0;}
```

Comment: forgot to mention that the position: fixed is in there in order for .stream to have it's own scrollbar that automatically extends to the size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
html,
body {
  background: grey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  background: blue;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
}
.outer .boxA {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background: pink;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.outer .boxC {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background: yellow;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.outer .inner {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.outer .inner .stream {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 0;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="boxA">
    <h3>Some content</h3>
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="header">
      <h2>blah</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="stream">
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
      <p>Hello 123 456 789 k thx bye</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxC">
    <h3>Box C</h3>
    <p>yadda yadda</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: forgot to mention that the position: fixed is in there in order for .stream to have it's own scrollbar that automatically extends to the size of the window.